# Why is there no badge for voting to close questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Out of curiosity, why is there no badge for voting to close questions? There seem to be badges (bronze at least) for using every other feature on the site pretty much, and I think it would be nice to show some appreciation to those people that find duplicates for example, or otherwise keep the site uncluttered and on topic.

Answer (score 4):

Because its just a mean to an end, not a goal in itself.

Besides, being able to vote to close is a privilege in itself, its a sign from the system that we trust you to draw the conclusion whether a quesiton belongs on our site or not.

It would be more useful if voting to close counted towards the Deputy and Marshal badge, because its like flagging, but you no longer need a moderator to follow up on it.

Comment: Not seeing a difference in that regard from editing...

Comment: It'd make sense to award being the first one to VTC for questions that are later closed.

Comment: Perhaps @DanielBeck, though if it counted towards Deputy it would make that badge 'easier' to obtain. As for editing, you even get rep for editing below 2k rep and anyone can propose an edit, so I don't think they're the same

Comment: @IvoFlipse It's a gold badge for a reason.